# App Crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

Yesterday, I released a new version of my app and today i found, a lot of users that upgraded form old version, encountered a crash.

After checking the crash log, Ii still can't find what the problem is and so, i come here to seek help.

The crash log shows, an unknown thread crash, and it looks like the APP have not finish launch, and none of my code was running.

I can't reproduce the crash when i run the APP from XCode

And I can's reproduce the crash when i newly install the APP from appStore

Below is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 7E991A17-1EAE-41CD-9B5D-ED915DEEB149
CrashReporter Key:   18ac1fb1671fd0ac6d2bde874eca5e132946f8f7
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         YoudaoDictNormal [3843]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1FE76C37-584F-4D8B-A700-E72582DFB0ED/YoudaoDictNormal. app/YoudaoDictNormal
Identifier:      YoudaoDictNormal
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]


Date/Time:       2013-07-16 00:12:21.128 +0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000b6d2
Highlighted Thread:  1


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x3bda7648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                       0x3bce04ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib                       0x3bcd2df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32


Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x3bdb7d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd05cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd05a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd058a0 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x3bdb7d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd05cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd05a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3bd058a0 start_wqthread + 4


Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x000a50f8    r1: 0x2fd68cd4      r2: 0x000a4fd4      r3: 0x2fd68d08
    r4: 0x2ff0614c    r5: 0x2ff060ec      r6: 0x000a4ebd      r7: 0x0000002f
    r8: 0x2ff086ac    r9: 0x0000ab00     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000049
    ip: 0x1c52c200    sp: 0x2fd67a20      lr: 0x2fef251d      pc: 0x000a4e88
  cpsr: 0x80000030
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in that error. I suggest you add an error reporting framework to your app, which will help you get a detailed error. I've used [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) and liked it a lot.

Comment: thanks for you suggest, but we do have a crash reporting framework, crashlytics, but it did not collect any crash report about this crash. so i guess the app is not finish launching when the crash occur

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information here, as others pointed out, but this appears to be a problem when upgrading. You didn't mention how you tested this, but you should test it basically like this:

- Use two projects, one with the previously released version, and one with the new one.
- Run the previously released version of the app. Do some typical stuff, then close.
- Now run the new verion of the app.

If there is an upgrade problem, you should be able to trigger it this way.

Comment: Thanks for you advise, but actually, we do have test the upgrade, and it will not crash, only upgrade through app store will cause the crash. So, it's very weird, we have requested TSI from apple, but have  not resolved yet.